# Working with java's native method

Tags: java

Im new to java and currently learning native methods, when I create following files :

**Main.java**:

```
public class Main {
    public native int intMethod(int i);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("Main");
        System.out.println(new Main().intMethod(2));
    }
}
```

**Main.c**:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "Main.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Main_intMethod(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint i) {
  return i * i;
}
```

**Compile and run**:

```
javac Main.java
javah -jni Main
gcc -shared -fpic -o libMain.so -I${JAVA_HOME}/include \
  -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux Main.c
java -Djava.library.path=. Main
```

**Output**:

```
4
```

But, when I do this :

**troller.java**:

```
public class troller {
    public native int intMethod(int i);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("troller");
        System.out.println(new troller().intMethod(2));
    }
}
```

**troller.c**:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "troller.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Main_intMethod(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint i) {
  return i * i;
}
```

**Compile and run**:

```
javac troller.java
javah -jni troller
gcc -shared -fpic -o libMain.so -I${JAVA_HOME}/include \
  -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux Main.c
java -Djava.library.path=. troller
```

**Output**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no troller in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at troller.main(troller.java:4)
```

Why does the program stops working if I change the name ?

**EDIT** :
After looking at the answers, I've noticed certain inconsistencies and now recreated all files but the error persists:
**Native.java**

```
public class Native{
public native int intMethod(int i);
public static void main(String[] args){S
    System.loadLibrary("Native");
    System.out.println("In java... :)");
    System.out.println(new Native().intMethod(4));

}
}
```

**Native.c**

```
#include<jni.h>
#include"Native.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Native_intMethod(
JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint i){
printf("In C .... :)");
return i*i;
}
```

**compile and run**

```
javac Native.java 
javah -jni Native
gcc -shared -fpic -o libMain.so -I${JAVA_HOME}/include  \
 -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux Native.c
java -Djava.library.path=. Native
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Native in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at Native.main(Native.java:4)
```

Comment: When you are compiling for troller, you have `-I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux Main.c` main still listed as a file. Shouldn't that be `troller.c`?

Answer (score 3):

When you generate the `.h` stub for native methods with `javah` it include the package and class name of the class.  This is so you can have the same method name in different classes.

```
Java_Main_intMethod
```

needs to be renamed to

```
Java_troller_intMethod
```

You also have to change the method name if the class is the same but the package changes.

Note: `C` doesn't have `@Override` and you can implement methods which are not declared in your `.h` file. ;)

Comment: @PournimaBedarkar I didn''t suggest you rename the file, in fact I pointed out that the name of the file didn't matter. I suggest you read my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rename Main to Troller you need to do it consistently. But your native library is still called libMain.so. So when you try to load the library troller, it fails because that's the wrong name.

And since your C file is now called troller.c, your gcc command either shouldn't work or you're compiling the wrong file.

Comment: This is the cause of the error. +1 Once this is fixed, look at my answer which is the next problem.

Comment: Yes, the cause of this error is libMain.so but of course, you will then get other errors because of the other references to Main which should be Troller.

Comment: I've fixed the command but error persists, look at the post I've edited

Comment: You need to call your lib libXXX where XXX is the parameter you provide to System.loadLibrary. So if you call System.loadLibrary("Native"), then your file needs to be called libNative.so (not libMain.so).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on Java's native method and try to guess what could be the issue. 
In the second comply and run command

-I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux **Main.c**

looks like it should have troller.c instead of Main.c

Comment: The name of the `.c` file in `C` doesn't matter. It doesn't even have to have a `.c`

Comment: Basically, once you compiled your C file to a share library, the name of the source file (an how many source files you had) doesn't matter. Only the name of the so file is import. But of course if your source file is called troller.c and you try to compile Main.c (which doesn't exist) gcc will fail.

Comment: I've fixed the command but error persists, look at the post I've edited