# Java Native Method, gone something wrong

Tags: java, c++, exception, java-native-interface, native

I just tried new to learn native methods in java today. I successfully loaded the `Native.dll` file successfully but having the problem in method call, also I am unable to figure out what is happening wrong.

My snippet code are:

> NativeTest.java

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Chirag
 */

public class NativeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Loading Library nativeLib");
        try {
            Native n = new Native();
            System.out.println("Loading success");
            System.out.print("Enter a number to get cube: ");
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(x + " * " + x + " * " + x + " = " +       n.cubecal(x));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error loading native library");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class Native {

    static {
        System.setProperty("java.library.path", new File("").getAbsolutePath());
//        try {
//            Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
//            fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
//            fieldSysPath.set(null, null);
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//        }
        String arch = System.getProperty("sun.cpu.isalist");
        if (arch.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("amd64")) {
            System.loadLibrary("Native");
        } else {
            System.loadLibrary("Native");
        }
    }

    public native int cubecal(int x);

}
```

Compiled class by `javac NativeTest.java`

and makes the `header` file by `javah Native`

> Native.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Native */

#ifndef _Included_Native
#define _Included_Native
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    /*
    * Class:     Native
    * Method:    cubecal
    * Signature: (I)I
    */
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Native_cubecal
        (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

and one more snip

> Native.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Native.h"


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Native_cubecal
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint val){
        return val * val * val;
}
```

after all of this snip I am getting this error after executing this code

```
Loading Library Native
Loading success
Enter a number to get cube: 4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: javaapplication2.Native.cubecal(I)I
    at javaapplication2.Native.cubecal(Native Method)
    at javaapplication2.NativeTest.main(NativeTest.java:28)
C:\Users\Chirag\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

I know this can be achieved easily by only java code but I am trying native methods so that I can also use the benefits of C++ in my other java projects.

> Note: I added all relatives path to Project properties in Visual Studio 2012 follows `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\include` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\include\win32`

I also readed these articles [Working with java's native method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724344/working-with-javas-native-method) and [Java programming with JNI](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni.html) but always ended up with this error.

Please help and also explain me what this exception is about.

Thank you :)

Comment: Perhaps change the catch to `Throwable` (instead of `Exception`) to try get more details.

Comment: Using **Throwable** gives the same result..

Comment: yes - same result is expected.  But now the `Error` (not `Exception`) can be caught to hopefully provide more context about the cause.  Try printing `e.getMessage()`.

Comment: `e.getMessage()` gives only the root cause of the error/exception thrown

Comment: by trying this, only _javaapplication2.NativeCube.cubecal(I)I_ is printed

Comment: Why do you think you _uccessfully loaded the Native.dll_?

Comment: I am printing the message after loading code, if it throws the exception, the message _Loading success_ not printed instead it will give the message `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Native in java.library.path` or `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Chirag\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication2\Native .dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! finally I got answer after too much of testing. The full code is inside a ***package***, the problem in above snippets is I am not considering the package for creating the header file.. (hehehe... my mistake. sorry for that)

Updated Code snips are:

> NativeTest.java

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Chirag
 */
public class NativeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Loading library NativeCube");
        try {
            NativeCube n = new NativeCube();
            System.out.println("Loading Library NativeCube succeeded");
            System.out.print("Enter a number to get cube: ");
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(x + " * " + x + " * " + x + " = " + n.cubecal(x));
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println("Error loading library nativeLib: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class NativeCube {

    public NativeCube() {
        System.setProperty("java.library.path", new File("").getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("Pathes: " + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        String arch = System.getProperty("sun.cpu.isalist");
        if (arch.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("amd64")) {
            System.loadLibrary("NativeCube");
        } else {
            System.loadLibrary("NativeCube_x86");
        }
    }

    public native int cubecal(int x);

}
```

Created header file by `javah javaapplication2.NativeCube`

> javaapplication2_NativeCube.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class javaapplication2_NativeCube */

#ifndef _Included_javaapplication2_NativeCube
#define _Included_javaapplication2_NativeCube
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    /*
    * Class:     javaapplication2_NativeCube
    * Method:    cubecal
    * Signature: (I)I
    */
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_javaapplication2_NativeCube_cubecal
        (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

> Main.cpp

```
#include "javaapplication2_NativeCube.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_javaapplication2_NativeCube_cubecal
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint val){
        return val * val * val;
}
```

and the output of the program is

```
Loading library NativeCube
Pathes: C:\Users\Chirag\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication2
Loading Library NativeCube succeeded
Enter a number to get cube: 12
12 * 12 * 12 = 1728
```

Learned a good chapter about not to skip the package name to create the header files.

Thanks [@Andrew S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6650475/andrew-s)  and [@Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3926506/sergey) for quick response. :)